# dismiss dialog window after onbackpressed

Tags: java, android

i have two activities. On 1st activity i have button after click on button it will show dialog window and after click on dialog button i will jump to 2nd activity.
On 2nd acitivity i have custom button which is calling **onBackPressed()** method:

```
private void btnBackListener(){
   btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 onBackPressed();
            }
        });    
    }
```

**My Problem is** when im on 2nd activity and i call onBackPressed(); it will jump into 1nd activity but also dialog is visibile. How to prevent showing that dialog after btnBack clicked in 2nd activity?

Comment: dismiss the dialog before you move to the second activity... (or show the code inside the click listener of the dialog).

Comment: solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think best option would be to close dialog before opening 2nd activity.